# Path to access database with a published C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, publish

I need to code the path to an access database after its been published/ installed to a device.

How would I get the path to the access database (for connection string) after its been installed on any device?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways

**Winform**
`Application.StartupPath`

> - returns the StartupPath parameter (can be set when run the application)

`System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`

> - returns the current directory, which may or may not be the folder where the application is located. The same goes for
>     `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. In case you are using this in a DLL
>     file, it will return the path of where the process is running (this is
>     especially true in ASP.NET)

**Web**

```
ttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath();
```

> - to get the current web application root directory

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```